# Where is the maintenance mode value in the database?

Tags: 8, maintenance-mode

I know the maintenance mode value used to be in the variables table, but in D8 that table is replaced by (or joined with) the config table, but I couldn't find any row with that name.

Where is it located now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer a part of the config system; it's a part of the [state system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview) which is stored in the `key_value` table as a part of the `state` `collection`.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. 
So how will a MySQL query that turns off maintenance mode look like?
UPDATE `key_value` SET `value` = '????????' WHERE `name` = 'system.maintenance_mode';

Comment: You don't need to touch the DB directly. Use the state API. You can find example code by searching this site.

Comment: Yes, with:
\Drupal::state()->set('system.maintenance_mode', FALSE);
But in some cases I want to change the database, is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 8 and 9:

First check the system.maintenance_mode value:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `key_value` 
WHERE `name` = 'system.maintenance_mode'
```

Then update the value:

```
UPDATE `key_value` 
SET `value` =   'b:0;'
WHERE `name` = 'system.maintenance_mode' AND `value` =  'b:1;'
```

Then empty all tables starting with "cache":

```
TRUNCATE `cachetags`;
TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE `cache_config`;
TRUNCATE `cache_container`;
TRUNCATE `cache_data`;
TRUNCATE `cache_default`;
TRUNCATE `cache_discovery`;
TRUNCATE `cache_dynamic_page_cache`;
TRUNCATE `cache_entity`;
TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE `cache_page`;
TRUNCATE `cache_render`;
TRUNCATE `cache_toolbar`;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (depending on your use case) is to [use drush](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-maintenance.html):

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0
drush cr
```